# Custom TableAdapter Delete Method Override

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm attempting to overload the "Delete" method of a TableAdapter ([approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233697.aspx)).  How can I execute an SQL statement from 'here' to handle the delete?

I've got:

```
Namespace AFL_BackendDataSetTableAdapters

    Partial Class Log_entry_unitTableAdapter

        Public Overloads Function Delete(ByVal LogEntryID As Integer) As Integer

            Dim SQL As String

            SQL = "DELETE FROM log_entry_unit WHERE log_entry_unit_id=" & LogEntryID

            '?????.Execute SQL

            Return 0

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

The overload is working fine, but I don't know how to do the hard part and actually manipulate the data from here.  Previously, I've just gone into the Dataset Designer and manually updated the generated methods to work like I want them, but whenever I use the wizard to regenerate the dataset, that (as expected) gets overwritten.

I've previously only ever manipulated Data using the generated methods, and now I'm stuck.

**EDIT w/ Final Answer**
Based on William's help below here's the final working solution (Note I just had to use OleDb instead of SQL since my Dataset is Access:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Namespace AFL_BackendDataSetTableAdapters

    Partial Class Log_entry_unitTableAdapter

        Public Overloads Function Delete(ByVal LogEntryID As Integer) As Integer

            Dim queryString As String = "DELETE FROM log_entry_unit WHERE log_entry_unit_id=" & LogEntryID
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, Connection)
            Dim r As Integer

            Try
                Connection.Open()
                r = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                r = 0
            Finally
                Connection.Close()                
            End Try

            Return r

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardcoded a connection string for reference only. This should be in a config file. As an example:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = _
        "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;" _
        & "Integrated Security=true"

    Dim queryString As String = "DELETE FROM log_entry_unit WHERE log_entry_unit_id=" & LogEntryID

    ' Create and open the connection in a using block. This
    ' ensures that all resources will be closed and disposed
    ' when the code exits.
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        ' Create the Command
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)

        ' Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' handle exception here
        End Try
    End Using
```

**EDIT**

I probably should of mentioned you will probably want to fill your adapter again after the delete.

Comment: This answer really isn't relevant because it doesn't modify an existing table adapter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I disagree. It is relevant. You still need the ADO.NET code. After the delete, they should fill the adapter again. Perhaps that is something that should be included in the answer.

Comment: This is conceptually what I was looking for.  I don't need to update the existing table adapater because I want to do that outside this method.  This is an access connection so I think I need to use OleDb instead of SqlConnection, but from my first look, it looks like it'll be the same sort of thing.  If I get stuck, I'll open a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrINClHOF Thats good. Someone unfortunately downvoted my answer. Anyway, glad it got you in the right direction.